# column to row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe:

```
Index Uniprot    ID1   ID2      P1       P2      
1     O00141     2r5tA 3hdmA    2r5tA_1  3hdmA_9
2     O00141     2r5tA 3hdmA    2r5tA_2  3hdmA_1
3     O00141     2r5tA 3hdmA    2r5tA_7  3hdmA_7
4     O15021     2w7rB 2w7rA    2w7rB_2  2w7rA_2
```

and want output to be like this way:

```
O00141 2r5tA 2r5tA_1 2r5tA_2 2r5tA_7
O00141 3hdmA 3hdmA_9 3hdmA_1 3hdmA_7              
O15021 2w7rB 2w7rB_2
O15021 2w7rA 2w7rA_2
```

I used transpose in pandas.T and got somewhat similar output but only got linear row:

```
Uniprot  O00141   O00141   O00141   O15021
ID1      2r5tA    2r5tA    2r5tA    2w7rB
ID2      3hdmA    3hdmA    3hdmA    2w7rA
P1       2r5tA_1  2r5tA_2  2r5tA_7  2w7rB_2
P2       3hdmA_9  3hdmA_1  3hdmA_7  2w7rA_2
```

Comment: Can you format your data frame so we can get a better sense of what it looks like and what you want? Also, it is helpful to include code you’ve already tried.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for df.T which makes transposition of dataframe

Comment: dont understand your output...

Comment: reformatted. Plz check it

Comment: I think your could just transpose columns (P1, P2, ID1, ID2) and add Uniprot before them?

Comment: Transpose columns only (P1, P2, ID1, ID2) won't help me bcoz it produces different Uniprot names into the same row. I want different Uniprot associated values in different rows as I shown in my ideal output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to iterate each row, but not complex, the idea is to create a dict with the data wanted and use [DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
data="""
Index Uniprot   P1       P2       ID1     ID2   
1     O00141    2r5tA_1  3hdmA_9  2r5tA 3hdmA
2     O00141    2r5tA_2  3hdmA_1  2r5tA 3hdmA
3     O00141    2r5tA_7  3hdmA_7  2r5tA 3hdmA
4     O15021    2w7rB_2  2w7rA_2  2w7rB 2w7rA
"""
#create the sample dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

#Uniprot have to be sorted 
df = df.sort_values(by= 'Uniprot')
dico = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    key1 = row.Uniprot + 'C1';key2 = row.Uniprot + 'C2'
    if key1 not in dico:
        dico[key1] = [row.Uniprot, row.ID1, row.P1]
        dico[key2] = [row.Uniprot, row.ID2, row.P2]
    else:
        dico[key1] = dico[key1] + [row.P1]
        dico[key2] = dico[key2] + [row.P2]

maxlen = max ([len(l) for l in dico.values()])
for k in dico.keys():
    d = len(dico[k])
    dico[k] = dico[k] + [''] * (maxlen - len(dico[k]))

df_result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico).T.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_result)
```

output:

```
        0      1        2        3        4
0  O00141  2r5tA  2r5tA_1  2r5tA_2  2r5tA_7
1  O00141  3hdmA  3hdmA_9  3hdmA_1  3hdmA_7
2  O15021  2w7rB  2w7rB_2                  
3  O15021  2w7rA  2w7rA_2
```

Comment: Could you help me with similar one @Frenchy, I've tried myself but didnt work. I've similar data but with extra column:

Input data:
Index Uniprot1   P1        ID1                 Uniprot2 P2        ID2   
0 P31749  1h10A  1h10A_1_N P31749  1unqA  1unqA_1_N
1 P31749  1h10A  1h10A_2_N P31749  1unrA    1unrA_1_N
2 P31749  1unpA  1unpA_1_P Q04759  2ennA  2ennA_4_N, 2ennA_5_N

Output should be :
 0  1  2    3  
0 P31749   1h10A    1h10A_1_N    1h10A_2_N     
1 P31749    1unqA   1unqA_1_N 
2 P31749   1unrA         1unrA_1_N
3 Q04759   2ennA   2ennA_4_N, 2ennA_5_N

Comment: @rajiv its complex to read your question in a comment and i think there are some errors in your sample for example the value 1unpA 1unpA_1_P doesnt in your output. and the algorithm seems different from my initial answer. I suggest you to ask another question and i 'll see

Comment: @Frency plz have a look my new question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694594/column-to-row-in-pandas-with-dictionary