# column to row in pandas with dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a df as follows:

```
input_data = """
Index U1   P1   ID1    U2   P2  ID2   
0     A    A1   A1_3   D    D1  D1_7
1     A    A1   A1_2   E    E1  E1_4
2     A    A1   A1_1   E    E2  E2_6
3     A    A1   A1_4   F    F1  F1_12
4     B    B1   B1_1   A    A2  A2_1
5     B    B1   B1_2   G    G1  G1_3
6     C    C1   C1_5   H    H1  H1_5
7     A    A1   A1_5   F    F1  F1_3
8     A    A1   A1_1   E    E2  E2_3
"""
```

I want to have a matrix format
[Matrix order as most repeated P1's (eg: A1)]

desired output:

```
A   A1  A1_1        A1_2     A1_3    A1_4    A1_5
D   D1                       D1_7
E   E1              E1_4
E   E2  E2_6,E2_3
F   F1                               F1_12   F1_3
A   A2
G   G1
H   H1
```

Comment: i dont understant the logic, i suppose there are errors in "Here maximum repeated P1 is 3qkmA"  -> 3qkmA_1_P? -> 3qkmA_5_N ? ->3qkmA_4_N?

Comment: yes, P1 name with a number of ID1 or ID2. When I mention maximum here, P1 (3qkmA) have more ID1's (3qkmA_1_P, 3qkmA_2_N, 3qkmA_3_N, 3qkmA_4_N, 3qkmA_5_N) than any others.

Comment: So the maximum ID's comes first and rest follows the order.
 Please note that example output order always follows this way: 

P31749    3qkmA   3qkmA_1_N   \n
Q16512    4othA    4othA_6_N    \n

shouldn't be as :

P17612  3ambA  3ambA_12_N  3ambA_3_N       \n                          
Q16512  4otgA    4otgA_4_N      4othA_6_N        \n

Comment: i dont understant why P17612  is not only on one line ? in your result there are 2 lines for this value....

Comment: @Frency. That was a mistake. corrected. P17612 should be on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a solution:

```
data = """
Index U1   P1   ID1    U2   P2  ID2   
0     A    A1   A1_3   D    D1  D1_7
1     A    A1   A1_2   E    E1  E1_4
2     A    A1   A1_1   E    E2  E2_6
3     A    A1   A1_4   F    F1  F1_12
4     B    B1   B1_1   A    A2  A2_1
5     B    B1   B1_2   G    G1  G1_3
6     C    C1   C1_5   H    H1  H1_5
7     A    A1   A1_5   F    F1  F1_3
8     A    A1   A1_1   E    E2  E2_3
"""


# create the sample dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['U1_P1'] = '(' + df['U1'].astype(str) + ',' + df['P1'] + ')'
df['U2_P2'] = '(' + df['U2'].astype(str) + ',' + df['P2'] + ')'
df.drop(['U1', 'U2', 'P1', 'P2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['ID1', 'U2_P2','U1_P1']).ID2.agg([('ID2', ', '.join)]).reset_index()

df_temp = df.groupby(['U1_P1'])['ID1'].agg('count').reset_index()
max_value = df_temp.loc[df_temp['ID1'].idxmax()]['ID1']
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp['ID1'] == max_value].reset_index()

for i, row in df_temp.iterrows():
    u1_p1 = row['U1_P1']
    filter = (df['U1_P1'] == u1_p1)
    dfx = df[filter].groupby(['U1_P1'])['ID1'].apply(list).reset_index()
    cols = [dfx['U1_P1'][0]] + dfx['ID1'][0]
    dfx = df.groupby(['U2_P2', 'ID1']).ID2.max().unstack().reset_index().fillna('').rename(columns={'U2_P2': cols[0]})
    for col in dfx.columns:
        if col not in cols:
            dfx.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

    print(dfx)
```

output dfx:

```
ID1  (A,A1)        A1_1  A1_2  A1_3   A1_4  A1_5
0    (A,A2)                                     
1    (D,D1)                    D1_7             
2    (E,E1)              E1_4                   
3    (E,E2)  E2_6, E2_3                         
4    (F,F1)                          F1_12  F1_3
5    (G,G1)                                     
6    (H,H1)
```

Comment: sorry i dont understant what you want exactly....following your sample which have lot errors and the expected output, i dont see the logic.. could you modify your question, with the right input and the expected output....i dont see if you want to order the output, i dont understant why you concat the output and i see 2 dataframes in the output....dont forget my english is not my first langage...

Comment: @Frency: I'm sorry for providing you the complex data. 
I've changed the data into general alphabets. Could you able to understand and get the output I wanted. Many thanks.

Comment: in your matrix, there is a maximun of 1 item by pair(column, row), ?

Comment: There is no maximum. 1 item can have more pairs.

Comment: for example i could have for (A1_1, E2) -> [E2_6, E2_3]

Comment: Yes, it can have... I've included that example (A1_1, E2) -> [E2_6, E2_3] in input_data.

Comment: ok and what i select if i have 2 or more same number of repeated P1?

Comment: We can go with maximum pairs P1 have, if possible?

Comment: so we do a result matrix for each P1?

Comment: Not necessarily. But my data have only 1-3  same number of maximum repeated P1 and can do matrix for each of 3 individually or JUST go with 1 repeated who can have more pair list? Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: i'll see.... first feeling its easier to do a matrix for each max repeated P1.. (same process)

Comment: yes, I guess so. Since I don't have much-repeated P1's, doing matrix for each is easier!

Comment: ok see my new solution..i dunno if the order is important for you

Comment: Thank you. What I've to change if I am interested in another item which has the same no.of maximum repeated P1?

Comment: my solution is okay with more same number of maximum repeated P1.  the df_temp contains all items with same number..and you loop after and print each dataframe dfx

Comment: Could you look my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001138/create-a-matrix-two-data-frame-with-pandas?noredirect=1#comment98648759_56001138